# Why Redis Publish operation's time complexity is O(M+N)

Tags: redis

As per Redis website, Time complexity of a publish is O(N+M).

*Time complexity: O(N+M) where N is the number of clients subscribed to the receiving channel and M is the total number of subscribed patterns (by any client).*

I might be wrong, but why can't it send message to all the client asynchronously using some asyn API (as writing message to network stream is I/O bound operation)?

Comment: It can and it will in an upcoming version... just not yet.

Comment: @ItamarHaber How would sending messages to all the client asynchronously change the complexity, as I see it would still need to do the same number of operations?

Comment: @Davor, If code is written synchronously, It will send message to first subscriber and then wait. Once it is done, it start sending to next subscriber. But if we do it asynchronously, Redis server can send message to multiple subscribers and take the benefit of parallelism.

Comment: @Itamar, I have one more question. We are using single ConnectionMultiplexer object for our subscriber web application. Is this single object sufficient for our subscriber application (average load). or we should create multiple ConnectionMultiplexer for a web server and share the load (even for a single web server)?

Comment: It might be faster overall but I don't think it would actually change the complexity. You still need to go through all the messages and clients. Complexity is not about how long the operation lasts rather how many you need to do to accomplish the goal.